# six cameras selection for jetson xavier

Tags: cameras

What six cameras do you recommend for a university project using a jetson xavier nx?

I am getting into self driving from a software point of view and camera selection becomes very difficult for me. I know that things like hdr or wide visual field are important, but there are so many options that I don't know which one to choose to start the project.
In this case the cameras would not be for high speeds aand these are the official options: https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetson-partner-supported-cameras?t1_max-resolution=4K&t1_supported-jetson-products=xavier

Comment: you have to determine exactly what specifications you need and then go shopping ... for example, `would not be for high speeds` is not a technical specification

Comment: I know very little about hardware and it is not the goal of the project. There are so many options that I honestly feel very lost. So I would really appreciate any specific hardware advice.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* user60108, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.